# Should I follow specific naming pattern for my foreign key, if I want to map my database tables using ado.net Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am reading the following tutorial regarding Entity Framework which uses the code-first approach [Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

and it mentioned that for EF to interpret FKs, between these two classes, I need to use the following 2 naming patterns or rules:-

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Then Entity Framework interprets a property as a foreign key property:

- **Rule1** if it's named `<navigation property name><primary key property name>` (for example, `StudentID` for the `Student` navigation property since the Student entity's primary key is ID).
- **Rule2** foreign key properties can also be named the same simply `<primary key property name>` (for example, `CourseID` since the Course entity's primary key is `CourseID`).

but if I already have a database and I am not following this naming pattern will this be a problem? For example let say I define the `Student-->Enrollment` relation as follow inside my sql server `Enrollment.StudentNo ---> Student.studentID` , where I define a field called `StudentNo` as the FK to the `student.studentid` (i did this for testing purposes), so will this cause any problem? From my own test I noted that EF will be happily mapping `Enrollment.StudentNo` with `Student.StudentId` (even I can define the FK to be named "`NoNamePetten`"),, so are the above two Rules valid only when using code-first approach and i do not need to follow them if i am using DB-first approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Database-First, and the relationship exists in your SQL database, then it should be fine. EF is smart enough to do the mapping in the generated context code.

If you're using Code-First, you don't always need to follow that convention. You can call the relevant fields whatever your heart desires, but you need to tell EF what exactly the relationship is between them. You can do this in one of 2 ways: With the Fluent API in your DbContext class, or with Data Annotations in your entity class (my personal favorite).

To do what you're asking, you would do the following in your `Enrollment` class:

```
public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Student")]
public int StudentNo { get; set; }

public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the great repl. sometimes lot of approaches and techniques and also many books talks about these rules for naming patterns, then you realize that these do not apply in my case as i am using DB-first approach ...

Comment: You're welcome! May I also recommend that, if you're looking into learning about EF, that you also take a look at Reverse Engineer Code-First. It will take a existing database and create individual code classes just like Code-First (as opposed to the T4 that Database-First does). I only mention that because, for EF 7, they will be moving away from Database-First.